# Get exit(1) from Python in shell

Tags: python, shell

I have python program, which is running from shell.
When there is an error in python, it will exit with exit(1) or something else, and I need shell program to get that answer, if there is error, run this program again.

Comment: Are you writing a shell script?

Comment: both, python program and shell script

Comment: Yes, but the real question is about shell scripting.

Comment: @glglgl yes, but i mentioned python because there can be something special for python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exit code can be found in the $? See the example:

```
python yourprogram.py
if [[ $? != 0 ]] ; then 
   dosomething
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, shell script automatically gets exit number, i used it with while $? = 1 and it works now very good.

Comment: @EminMastizada I would work close to the standard and not check for `== 1`, but for `!= 0` indeed. Usually, an exit code of 0 means success, any other value means failure or a special condition, where the meaning of each value is defined by the called program. So if you just want to check for failure, do that. Only check for `= 1` if the 1 has another meaning than 2 would have.

Comment: (Especially as the OP says "or something else", so the exit code isn't limited to 1, it can also have other values.)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about Python in this case. You capture the exit code as with any other program:

- either you evaluate `$?` where you have this code directly, as in [sanyi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21040222/296974), or
- you embed the program call in an `if` or `while` condition, where its non-zero-ness is checked:

  ```
  if ! python yourprogram.py; then 
     dosomething
  fi
  ```

Comment: When i searched for this, in most places they called shell script from python, and its not good solution for my project. And I don't have a lot experience with shell scripts.