# python selenium, Firefox suddenly goes blank and stop working

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, browser

I am using python selenium to parse large amount of data from more than 10,000+ urls. The browser is Firefox.

For each url, a Firefox browser will be opened and after data parsing, it will be closed, and wait 5 seconds before opening the next url through Firefox.

However, it happened twice these days, everything was running great, all of a sudden, the newly opened browser is blank, it is not loading the url at all. In real life experience, sometimes, even when I manually open a browser, searching for something, it is blank too.

The problem is, when this happened, there is no error at all, even when I wrote the except code to catch any exception, meanwhile I'm using `nohup` command to run the code, it will record any exception too, but there is no error at all. And once this happened, the code won't be executed any more, and many urls are left there without being parsed.... If I re-run the code on the rest urls, it works fine again.

Here is my code (all the 10,000+ urls are in comment_urls list):

```
for comment_url in comment_urls:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/Users/devadmin/Documents/geckodriver')
    driver.get(comment_url)
    time.sleep(5)
    try:
       // here is my data parsing code .....
       driver.quit()   // the browser will be closed when the data has been parsed
       time.sleep(5)   // and wait 5 secods

    except:
        with open(error_comment_reactions, 'a') as error_output:
            error_output.write(comment_url+"\n")
        driver.quit()
        time.sleep(5)
```

At the same time, in that data parsing part, if there will be any exception, my code will also record the exception and close the driver, wait 5 seconds. But so far, no error recorded at all.

I tried to find similar problems and solutions online, but those are not helpful.

So, currently, I have 2 questions in mind:

1. Have you met this problem before and do you know how to deal with it? It is network problem or selenium problem or browser problem?
2. Or is there anyway in python, that it can tell the browser is not loading the url and it will close it?

Comment: try to turn off hardware acceleration: https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Procedures-to-diagnose-and-fix/Troubleshoot-extensions-themes-and-hardware-acceleration-issues/ta-p/1616#w_turn-off-hardware-acceleration

Comment: I started with this solution, the code kept running these days, but today it suddenly stopping without finishing. The good news is, this time, the browser no longer crash, but there is a pop-up window, asking for the master password for a security service and stopped my code. However it didn't tell which security service. So I'm wondering it's because Mac may has some security setting? Or it's the security protection of our school lab? Or any other reason? This machine has multiple accounts, the one I am using is not the master account. Any thought?

Comment: It depends on screenshot of that page and url. Without it guessing what happened is very hard. Firefox has own master password for firefox sync, but as I understood you don't use sync in selenium browser (Firefox driver). So it can be due to website or campus.

Answer (score 0):

For second problem, Prefer to use work queue to parse urls. One app should add all of them to queue (redis, rabbit-mq, amazon sqs and etc.) and then Second app should get 1 url from queue and try to parse it. In case if it will succeed, it should delete url from queue and switch to other url in queue. In case of exception it should os.exit(1) to stop app. Use shell to run second app, when it will return 1, meaning that error occurred, restart the app. Shell script: [Get exit(1) from Python in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040001/get-exit1-from-python-in-shell/21040222#21040222)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your 2 questions:

1) Yes I have found selenium to be unpredictable at times. This is usually a problem when opening a browser for the first time which I will talk about in my solution. Try not to close the browser unless you need to.

2) Yes you can use the WebDriverWait() class in selenium.webdriver.support.wait

You said you are parsing thousands of comments so just make a new get request with the webdriver you have open.

I use this in my own scraper with the below code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://someurl.com")
table = WebDriverWait(browser,60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "table")))`
```

The variable browser is just webdriver.Firefox() class.

It is a bit long but what it does is wait for a specific html tag to exist on the page with a timeout of 60 seconds.

It is possible that you are experiencing your  own time.sleep() locking the thread up as well. Try not to use sleeps to compensate for things like this.